# Find closest matching distances for a set of points in a distance matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, distance, vectorization, template-matching

I have a matrix of measured angles between M planes

```
 0    52    77    79
52     0    10    14
77    10     0     3
79    14     3     0
```

I have a list of known angles between planes, which is an N-by-N matrix which I name `rho`. Here's is a subset of it (it's too large to display):

```
 0    51    68    75    78    81    82
51     0    17    24    28    30    32
68    17     0     7    11    13    15
75    24     7     0     4     6     8
78    28    11     4     0     2     4
81    30    13     6     2     0     2
82    32    15     8     4     2     0
```

My mission is to find the set of M planes whose angles in `rho` are nearest to the measured angles.
For example, the measured angles for the planes shown above are relatively close to the known angles between planes 1, 2, 4 and 6.

Put differently, I need to find a set of points in a distance matrix (which uses cosine-related distances) which matches a set of distances I measured. This can also be thought of as matching a pattern to a mold.

In my problem, I have M=5 and N=415.

I really tried to get my head around it but have run out of time. So currently I'm using the simplest method: iterating over every possible combination of 3 planes but this is slow and currently written only for M=3. I then return a list of matching planes sorted by a matching score:

```
function [scores] = which_zones(rho, angles)
    N = size(rho,1);
    scores = zeros(N^3, 4);
    index = 1;
    for i=1:N-2
        for j=(i+1):N-1
            for k=(j+1):N
                found_angles = [rho(i,j) rho(i,k) rho(j,k)];
                score = sqrt(sum((found_angles-angles).^2));
                scores(index,:)=[score i j k];
                index = index + 1;
            end
        end;
    end
    scores=scores(1:(index-1),:); % was too lazy to pre-calculate #
    scores=sortrows(scores, 1);
end
```

I have a feeling `pdist2` might help but not sure how. I would appreciate any help in figuring this out.

Answer (score 1):

There is http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/dsearchn.html for closest point search, but that requires same dimensionality. I think you have to bruteforce find it anyway because it's just a special problem.

Here's a way to bruteforce iterate over all unique combinations of the second matrix and calculate the `score`, after that you can find the one with the minimum score.

```
A=[ 0    52    77    79;
   52     0    10    14;
   77    10     0     3;
   79    14     3     0];
B=[ 0    51    68    75    78    81    82;
   51     0    17    24    28    30    32;
   68    17     0     7    11    13    15;
   75    24     7     0     4     6     8;
   78    28    11     4     0     2     4;
   81    30    13     6     2     0     2;
   82    32    15     8     4     2     0];

M = size(A,1);
N = size(B,1);

% find all unique permutations of `1:M`
idx = nchoosek(1:N,M);
K = size(idx,1); % number of combinations = valid candidates for matching A

score = NaN(K,1);
idx_triu = triu(true(M,M),1);
Atriu = A(idx_triu);

for ii=1:K
    partB = B(idx(ii,:),idx(ii,:));
    partB_triu = partB(idx_triu);
    score = norm(Atriu-partB_triu,2);
end

[~, best_match_idx] = min(score);
best_match = idx(best_match_idx,:);
```

The solution of your example actually is `[1 2 3 4]`, so the upperleft part of `B` and not `[1 2 4 6]`.

This would theoretically solve your problem, and I don't know how to make this algorithm any faster. But it will still be slow for large numbers. For example for your case of `M=5` and `N=415`, there are `100 128 170 583` combinations of `B` which are a possible solution; just generating the selector indices is impossible in 32-bit because you can't address them all.

I think the real optimization here lies in cutting away some of the planes in the `NxN` matrix in a preceding filtering part.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, since I specifically wanted a non-brute-froce solution, I cannot accept it. I disagree with what you said about this not being a general problem. The way I described it is indeed specific, but I think that it's a version of a very general one, in fact. I think you can narrow it down to finding an intersection of a few sets. I'll work on it more, and if I don't find a better solution (or get a better answer), I'll accept yours.

Comment: You don't have to accept, I just saw your way of doing it and immediately thought that that could already be sped up a bit. Don't really had/have the time/knowledge to come up with a straightforward solution.